# Match full number only regular expression

Tags: javascript, python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am playing around with regular expression for trying to recognize dates and I have the following regular expression:

```
(([0]?[1-9])|^([1][3-9])|([1][0-2]))/([012]?[0-9]|[3][01])/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

The issue is that when I have an incorrect date (in America at least) like 14/02/2000 is still thinks 4/02/2000 is a date. How can I modify my regular expression so that it doesn't recognize part of the number?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the regular expression in word boundaries: `\b`, to indicate that there should be a non-word character before the first number.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
`^(([0]?[1-9])|([1][0-2]))\/([012]?[0-9]|[3][01])\/[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]$`
I added the `^` and `$`, and got rid of the `^([1][3-9])` at the first segment, I don't understand what is its purpose. I also escaped the slashes (`\/`)